# Generate permutations with symbols

Tags: ruby, strings, array, combinatorics

Goal: Create a combination of emails based from inputted first name, last name, middle name, and a domain. Add in common separators. Then I'll check which one is correct with the rapportive API. This is the first part of the bigger script.

If you are given the `string` variables

```
{fn}
{ln}
{fi}
{li}
{mi}
{mn}
```

How would you create the following?

```
{fn}
{ln}
{fn}{ln}
{fn}.{ln}
{fi}{ln}
{fi}.{ln}
{fn}{li}
{fn}.{li}
{fi}{li}
{fi}.{li}
{ln}{fn}
{ln}.{fn}
{ln}{fi}
{ln}.{fi}
{li}{fn}
{li}.{fn}
{li}{fi}
{li}.{fi}
{fi}{mi}{ln}
{fi}{mi}.{ln}
{fn}{mi}{ln}
{fn}.{mi}.{ln}
{fn}{mn}{ln}
{fn}.{mn}.{ln}
{fn}-{ln}
{fi}-{ln}
{fn}-{li}
{fi}-{li}
{ln}-{fn}
{ln}-{fi}
{li}-{fn}
{li}-{fi}
{fi}{mi}-{ln}
{fn}-{mi}-{ln}
{fn}-{mn}-{ln}
{fn}_{ln}
{fi}_{ln}
{fn}_{li}
{fi}_{li}
{ln}_{fn}
{ln}_{fi}
{li}_{fn}
{li}_{fi}
{fi}{mi}_{ln}
{fn}_{mi}_{ln}
{fn}_{mn}_{ln}
```

at the moment I am solving it by creating an `array` for each permutation

```
fi_perms = [fi].product ['_' + li,                                                                                                       
                           '_' + ln,                                                                                                       
                           '-' +li,                                                                                                        
                           '-' ln,                                                                                                         
                           '.' + li,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + ln,                                                                                                       
                           li,                                                                                                             
                           ln,                                                                                                             
                           mi '_' ln,                                                                                                      
                           mi '-' ln,                                                                                                      
                           mi + '.' + ln,                                                                                                  
                           mi + ln]                                                                                                        
  fn_perms = [fn].product ['_' + li,                                                                                                       
                           '_' + ln,                                                                                                       
                           '_' + mi '_' + ln,                                                                                              
                           '_' + mn '_' + ln,                                                                                              
                           '-' + li,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + ln,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + mi + '-' + ln,                                                                                            
                           '-' + mn + '-' ln,                                                                                              
                           '.' + li,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + ln,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + mi '.' +ln,                                                                                               
                           '.' + mn '.' ln,                                                                                                
                           li,                                                                                                             
                           ln,                                                                                                             
                           mi + ln,  
                           ln,                                                                                                             
                           mi + ln,                                                                                                        
                           mn + ln]                                                                                                        
  li_perms = [li].product ['_' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '_' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           fi,                                                                                                             
                           fn]                                                                                                             
  ln_perms = [ln].product [ln,                                                                                                             
                           '_' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '_' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '-' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + fi,                                                                                                       
                           '.' + fn,                                                                                                       
                           fi,                                                                                                             
                           fn]
```

because I will be using it later by adding it to another array like so

```
perms = li_perms + ln_perms + fi_perms + fn_perms
permutations = []

perms.count.times do |i|
    perms.each do |perm|
        permutations[i] = perm.join
    end
end

permutations[0] = ['fn.mn.ln']
```

Is there a better of doing this?

Comment: Is there any pattern in the expected permutations?

Comment: shouldn't the second `{fn}{mi}{ln}` be  `{fn}.{mi}{ln}`? and is the order required in that way exactly?

Comment: @Vogel612 it does not have to be exact.

Comment: Wild guess here — first name, last name, first initial, last initial, middle initial, middle name? What are you _really_ trying to accomplish, and why don't you ask that instead?

Comment: @200_success Create a combination of emails based from inputted first name, last name, middle name, and a domain. Add in common separators. Then I'll check which one is correct with the rapportive API. This is the first part of the bigger script.

Comment: This question is completely clear given his last comment, and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your list is not "all permutation", but is painstakingly built by hand, I would not suggest using array's `permutation` API or something like that, but keep the curated mode you are using.

I would suggest building it in a more readable way. In your way of `[fi].product[...]` it is very hard to follow which permutation exists, and which doesn't. The first list you show is more readable, and if you name your atoms correctly (`first_name` instead of `fn`), it makes it trivial to understand what you are trying to do. I would suggest building your permutation table as a string like this:

```
name_permutations = <<PERMS
{last_initial}{first_name}
{last_initial}.{first_name}
{last_initial}{first_initial}
{last_initial}.{first_initial}
{first_initial}{middle_initial}{last_name}
{first_initial}{middle_initial}.{last_name}
{first_name}{middle_initial}{last_name}
{first_name}.{middle_initial}.{last_name}
{first_name}{middle_name}{last_name}
{first_name}.{middle_name}.{last_name}
{first_name}-{last_name}
{first_initial}-{last_name}
{first_name}-{last_initial}
{first_initial}-{last_initial}
{last_name}-{first_name}
{last_name}-{first_initial}
{last_initial}-{first_name}
{last_initial}-{first_initial}
...
PERMS
```

And then use substitutions to get all permutations:

```
name_permutations.gsub('{first_name}', first_name)
                 .gsub('{last_name}', last_name)
                 .gsub('{middle_name}', middle_name)
                 .gsub('{first_initial}', first_initial)
                 .gsub('{middle_initial}', middle_initial)
                 .gsub('{last_initial}', last_initial)
                 .split($/)
```

Comment: I like this approach for the question posed, although I think the all possible permutations of names, initials, and separators is a more interesting problem.

Comment: @Jonah - For that you could `(1..9).map{ |i| [fi,fn,mi,mn,li,ln,'.','-','_'].permutations(i).map(&:join) }.flatten` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation)

Comment: Good point that's clever

Comment: @UriAgassi just a minor error that `permutations` should be singular `permutation`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I've made some changes to try to improve the readability of my answer.

You could just create a few simple helper methods.  Here's an example, based on the assumption that ordering is not important.  Rather than the usual approach of presenting the code and then showing how it is used, I have reversed those steps, as the code is so simple that most readers will be able to glean it merely from its application.

There are two helper methods, `gen` and `middle_with_seps`, The variables `fn`, `mn` and `ln` refer to "first name", "middle name" and "last name".  The first, middle and last initials are: `fi = fn[0]`, `mi = mn[0]` and `li = ln[0]`.  The constants should be self-explanatory.  (The application of the code is best appreciated when one of [these](https://archive.org/details/Wild_Bill_Hickok) is playing in the background.)

**Application**

```
fn, mn, ln = 'Wild', 'Bill', 'Hickok'

gen([fn, fi], DASH_USCORE                                    , [ln, li] ) +
gen([ln, li], DASH_USCORE                                    , [fn, fi] ) +
gen(li      , DOT                                            , fn       ) +
gen(li      , NOSPACE_DOT                                    , fi       ) +
gen(fn      , middle_with_seps(mi, DASH_USCORE + NOSPACE_DOT), ln       ) +
gen(fn      , middle_with_seps(mn, DASH_USCORE + NOSPACE_DOT), ln       ) +
gen(fi      , middle_with_seps(mi, DASH_USCORE + NOSPACE)    , ln       ) +
gen(fi      , middle_with_seps(mi+'.', NOSPACE)              , ln       )

#=> ["Wild_Hickok", "Wild_H", "Wild-Hickok", "Wild-H",
#      "W_Hickok", "W_H", "W-Hickok", "W-H",
#    "Hickok_Wild", "Hickok_W", "Hickok-Wild", "Hickok-W",
#      "H_Wild", "H_W", "H-Wild", "H-W",
#    "H.Wild", "HW", "H.W",
#    "Wild_B_Hickok", "Wild-B-Hickok", "WildBHickok", "Wild.B.Hickok",
#    "Wild_Bill_Hickok", "Wild-Bill-Hickok","WildBillHickok","Wild.Bill.Hickok",
#    "W_B_Hickok", "W-B-Hickok", "WBHickok",
#    "WB.Hickok"]
```

**Code**

```
NOSPACE     = ['']
DOT         = ['.']
NOSPACE_DOT = NOSPACE + DOT
DASH_USCORE = ['-', '_']

fi, mi, li = fn[0], mn[0], ln[0]

def combine_strings(s1, s2, s3) "#{s1}#{s2}#{s3}" end

def gen(left_strings, seps, right_strings)
  left_strings  = [left_strings].flatten
  seps          = [seps].flatten
  right_strings = [right_strings].flatten
  left_strings.each_with_object([]) { |l,a| seps.each { |sep|
    right_strings.each { |r| a << combine_strings(l, sep, r) } } }
end

def middle_with_seps(m, seps)
  seps.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| a << combine_strings(s, m, s) }  
end
```

**Explanation**

`gen()`'s arguments are as follows:

- `left_strings` : an array of strings for the left end of the string
- `seps`         : an array of separators (e.g., '', '.', '-', etc.)
- `right_strings`: an array of strings for the right end of the string

If `left_strings`, `seps` or `right_strings` is entered as a string, rather than an array of strings, it is converted to an array containing itself.  `gen` constructs an array of strings, one for each combination of strings taken from `left_strings`, `seps` and `right_strings`.

`middle_with_seps`'s arguments are as follows:

- `m` is the middle name or initial
- `seps` is the same as for the method `gen`

`middle_with_seps` creates an array of separators that is passed as the argument `seps` in `gen()` when the middle name or initial is to be included. Each element of that array is the (string) value of `m` bracketed by a separator (except in one case where the initial `'B'` is converted to `'B.'` (`'WB.Hickok'`). For example,

```
middle_with_seps(mi, DASH_USCORE + NOSPACE) #=> ["_B_", "-B-", "B"]
```

Comment: Why are you giving such unreadable names to your variables and functions? Your code is very hard to read, and you need to tell us the `la` is an array for the left end of the string, instead of calling it `left_end_strings` or something more meaningful - this _is_ code-review, after all...

Comment: @Uri, there was a method to my madness, even if I have miscalculated, as I appear to have done (for the author of code is usually not the best one to judge its readability). My intent was for the lines beginning `gen([fn, fi], ['_', '-']...` to tell the reader at a glance what the two helpers did. That wouldn't have worked if I had `generate_combinations([first_name, last_name], ['_', '-']...` as lines would have wrapped or required horizontal scrolling, defeating the purpose. I've made some changes to my answer. I welcome suggestions for further improvement.  Thanks.